# Symfony2.4 forms working on local computer but not on distant server

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm having a frustrating problem with all the forms of a Symfony2 website for a couple of days now.

In fact, every form are OK when my coworkers and I work on the project on our local computers (we're all on PC, Windows 7 64bits or 8.1 64bits, using WAMP 64bits too and having PHP v5.4 and Symfony v2.4.3 set on it). But when we want to test on our distant dev environment, there is no form that works properly: in the Symfony profiler, the problem seems to reside in the fact that **no POST parameters** go through the process of submitting the form. **But** once again, this situation **only** appears **when** the project is hosted on the **distant server**.

I have checked the configuration of the server because I thought it was a config issue, but everything looks just the same as what we have on our WAMPs.

I have also checked my config.yml file, just to see if something could be wrong in it, but I can't see any kind of "local-only" configuration.

Moreover, I've found a very few people telling that they encountered the same problem on the internet, but they never explained how they did to go through that.

As I said, I am currently on this issue for days now, and every suggestion and clue will be very welcome! 
Thank you for your time,

**[Edit 1]** This is a complementary information: the only difference between our local and remote configuration is that, on the remote server, the "short_open_tag" thing is enabled and, due to some provider restrictions, can't be disabled.
So I enabled it on my WAMP (and restarted it) to see if to see if the forms would keep working. And they do work with short_open_tag enabled on my local machine, so I assume that the problem is not from there.

Comment: Have you run the "check.php" script in the remote server to verify all necessary modules are installed? php app/check.php

Comment: @VictorHenriquez I have one warning for an optional recommendations: "short_open_tag should be disabled", but I can't disable it due to the host provider who doesn't allow that. I already knew it, so I tried to find if some short tags were in the project, but didn't find any. Could it still be the reason of the problem? (Thank you for your quick answer!)

Comment: short_open_tag shouldn't be the reason of this problem, but looks like is a server configuration issue. Maybe the apache server doesn't have the redirect module enabled or there are some missing php moudles. I'm inclined to think is a Apache configuration issue, so try to compare the modules you have enabled in your local server with the ones in the remote one: apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES

Comment: @VictorHenriquez since the remote server is not dedicated but shared, I'm not sure I can enable or disable some. The list of enabled Apache modules of this kind of server is here: link, and the list of the ones enabled locally is : 
- acces_compat
- actions
- alias
- allowmethods
- asis
- auth_basic
- authn_core
- authn_file
- authz_core
- authz_groupfile
- authz_host
- authz_user
- autoindex
- cgi
- dir
- env
- include
- isapi
- lbmethod
- log_config
- mime
- negotiation
- rewrite
- setenvif